# Apagar todos logs do console

Tags: javascript

há alguma forma de se apagar todos os logs do console e começar denovo, tipo eu inseri varios logs lá usando console.log, porém quero remover todos eles de uma vez só e recomeçar inserindo outros..

li sobre console.clear() só que nada acontece..

Comment: console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

Comment: Boa pergunta! Eu queria saber um meio de limpar o console inteiro após uma operação sigilosa (tipo um login via Ajax), pois os dados confidenciais ficam no console (não exatamente na área de log, mas ainda assim disponíveis) e não sei como limpá-los... >:(

Comment: `console.clear()` parece funcionar [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p958ra5f/2/) :/

Comment: @abfurlan funciona nao... http://jsfiddle.net/p958ra5f/4/

Comment: Aqui funciona, o chrome ainda exibe a mensagem `Console was cleared`, no FF também testei e funciona. Qual navegador você esta usando?

Comment: aparece essa mensagem aqui também mas os logs nao sao apagados.. @abfurlan

Comment: Está habilitado o check `Preserve log`?

Comment: Nao sei, uso Chrome no Mac OS @abfurlan

Comment: Entendi, veja este link [Console API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consoleclear)

Comment: utilize também os atalhos como CTRL + L

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O comando para limpar o console é `console.clear()`.

Caso não esteja limpando o console, você deve estar com a opção `Preserve log` ativada. Esta opção serve para impedir que outros scripts limpem o console, dificultando a depuração do código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Suporta Chrome & IE, não testei Opera e Firefox for testar é agradeço.

Enquanto de erro é só olhar o tutorial
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd548687(v=vs.94).aspx

até mais

```js
(function(){
  var msdn = console;
  Object.defineProperty( eval, "console", {
  get : function(){
      if( msdn._commandLineAPI ){
      throw "Navegador não suporta o objeto defineProperty!";
          }
      return msdn; 
  },
  set : function(val){
      msdn = val;
  }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script>
// TESTE de enviar console.log
console.log("OI BRASIL");
console.log("TESTADO");
console.log = function() {};
console.log("BORA OLIMPIADAS");
</script>
```